# How to read CoreML model Prediction MLMultiArray

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, coreml

I am new to CoreML and I have generated a coreML model that return the Double 9 × 4 matrix matrix as shown in image blow.

[image]

Here is the code that is working fine and giving me the MLMultiArray.

```
 let outFeatures = try model.prediction(from: input)
        
        // get all 4 featrue array from image
        
        // MLFeature Value
        //1 × 3 × 20 × 20 × 8
        let confidence = outFeatures.featureValue(for: "confidence")?.multiArrayValue
        let coordinates = outFeatures.featureValue(for: "coordinates")?.multiArrayValue
```

Now I have to read each row of the MLMultiArray and also the values of column of each row. I have search a lot on internet but did not find any looping method that can iterate on MLMultiArray. Any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/pytorch/ios-demo-app/tree/master/ObjectDetection this helped me to understand a a bunch of stuff, also search for some yolo coreML

Comment: Yes I have seen this one, but its returning VNVisionRectangeObject that already have the boxes and confidence in proper array.